# Is it common practice to connect power supply to a DB9?

Tags: can, radar, db9

[image]I got a project where many sensors which uses CAN were connected to a DB9.

And sensor power (24V and GND) too. I want to connect the DB9 terminal to power however how can I do it in a safe way? If I connect using tiny wires like the ones I use with Arduino might burn.

Above image was Lidar sensor which I had to buy the correct cable to work and worked. Now using Radar (Delphi ESR 2.5 24V) there is only one terminal and power input goes to a DB9 (like the one in the image)

Does anybody have ideas? Estimated current is around 900 mA.

[Please check two last pictures for terminal information](https://www.autonomoustuff.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/delphi-esr.pdf)

Comment: fairly common: I've seen serial port cards with optional +5V or +12V on pin9

Answer (score 4):

It is common, but only in systems which will never be connected to a serial port. If you do that, you get what you deserve.

Probably there is an exception in CANBus systems which are connected to a PC. Fortunately, most PCs these days don't have a serial port.

Comment: How can I connect to a power supply if power is on a DB9? I really don't get why it was set this way

Comment: You go to a distributor like Digikey and buy a matching DB9 connector. Then you either connect wires or build a PC board, depending on exactly which version you get. The come in pc board, wire wrap or wire socket. As to why? Well, the connectors are cheap, compact and carry enough current. What else can you ask for?

Comment: Thanks, I was planning to do like that but aren't the wires too tiny to support 24V and 900 mA? I thought it would be too much for them and could cause electric malfunction or get burned.

Comment: Nope. DB9s are generally rated for 5 A per contact. I've never seen a formal rating for voltage, but it'd guess at least 100 volts. I believe standard solder cup contacts will accept a 22 ga wire, and that's plenty.

Comment: Actually, a bit of research shows that some manufacturers provide solder cup contacts which will accept 20 ga.

Comment: CAN is a serial bus, but it has an entirely different db9 standard compared with ancient "serial port" RS-232. If you connect CAN directly to a PC you'll have a custom board with CAN DB9. Or far more likely, a CAN-to-USB adapter.

Comment: @Lundin - The point is that RS-232 and CANBus both use DB9s. I've never looked up the pin assignment comparison, but it wouldn't surprise me if plugging a CANBus into an RS-232 (or vice versa) might have unpleasant physical consequences.

Comment: A whole lot of very diverse things use DB9. Pretty much every field bus out there.

Answer (score 4):

D-Subminiature connectors are just that, connectors. They can be used for a variety of purposes besides computer serial ports (although that's probably their most familiar application).

Some companies make "power" D-Sub connectors, such as NorComp's Power-D series. These connectors have a set of larger power contacts among the smaller signal contacts. According to the first datasheet I pulled up, NorComp rates these connectors at 40 A for the power pins and 5 A for the signal pins. Of course, you have to use the right size wire inside your cable to pull that much current.

If you're limited to using DB-9 (it's actually a DE-9) and you're only drawing 900 mA, the pins seem to be rated anywhere from 3 to 5 A according to a quick parametric search on Digi-Key. The high-density D-Sub connectors are rated somewhat lower due to the smaller pin size.

Answer (score 2):

There is an industry standard DB9 pinout for CAN which is set by CANopen DS303.1 6.1:[image]

This is a widely accepted standard. Anyone deviating from this pin-out for CAN applications is making non-standard crap.

The intention here is clearly that this should be a pure data traffic connector. CAN_V+ is dedicated for supplying opto isolators, that use the signal ground CAN_GND. It is required that pin 3 and optional GND on pin 6 are connected internally. None of these were ever intended for noisy supply currents.

That being said, the least bad thing you can do if you do need to provide a supply through the same connector, is to do so by sacrificing pin 9 and 3. This given that you don't actually use galvanically isolated CAN or it will obviously not work. And you give up the signal ground, which could mean worse signal peformance.

By using 9 and 3 you at least ensure that you won't burn up other devices, but signal and/or EMC performance might suffer instead, depending on the quality and currents of your supply.

And well, obviously check the current ratings of connectors and cables. The average DB9 should be able to handle 0.9A just fine, but check the datasheets to be sure.